# "brothers in her bag"

Tags: dialogue, cinema

in the film The Maltese Falcon (1941) the private detective Miles said
"They have brothers in her bag."

context: the client, beautiful women Wonderly gave him two Dollar bill and after she left he examined one bill and said that.

what actually does he mean? can anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 4):

I expect it's a metaphorical / figurative reference meaning ***there are more dollar bills like that in her bag*** (i.e. - ***There's more where that came from*** as often said when someone wants to indicate that they can afford to pay more for something they want more of).

Comment: The fact that US banknotes all have well-known and long-standing pictures of presidents naturally leads to them being personified (they are often referred to as presidents, dead presidents, or by the president's name).

Comment: Well, I know Americans seem to like the idea of only electing presidents drawn from a small cadre of "ruling families" (the Kennedys, The Bushes,...) but I'm not sure that justifies saying that OP's cited use of "brothers" alludes to ***other presidents***. I think it's just a general-purpose figurative usage for ***more of the same***.